# mobile development through Php

Tags: php, mobile

I am quite new for both php and mobile app development. i want to develop an moblie app and my friend suggest php is best for it.
I need help in that, how can i start  app development. or any other technology to use. 
my main motive is app development.

Comment: download [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to test locally, read a book about PHP, code, debug, rinse and repeat

Comment: PHP for mobile app development? Unless you mean a web site that can be viewed with a mobile device, you got some bad advice.

Comment: so what should i use?? i just need to develop an app.

Comment: An app for what? iPhone, Android, Windows Phone...?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with static html sites first.

You can use a mobile framework such as http://jquerymobile.com/ for mobile UI.

PHP is server side scripting, you can use it to generate dynamic html if/when you need.

Comment: any other option then these,because it's seem  these are not as powerful and useful in app. development

Comment: You can use Phonegap to it in to a mobile app.  (I've only tried it with Android) 

http://phonegap.com/

There is also http://www.appcelerator.com/ (I've not used it myself)